# One or two weird linking errors with some inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, hyperlink, clang, linker-errors

I have the following short application (The original is taken from: https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/X86-assembly/Instructions/str) I just modified it (tried to...) to make it compilable on linux too.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char mema[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

void test4 (void)
{

    asm (
        "str mema\n"
    );

    printf ("\n[+] Test 4: STR\n");
    printf ("STR base: 0x%02x%02x%02x%02x\n", mema[0], mema[1], mema[2], mema[3]);

    if ((mema[0] == 0x00) && (mema[1] == 0x40))
        printf ("Result  : VMware detected\n\n");
    else
        printf ("Result  : Native OS\n\n");
}

int main () {

    test4();
}
```

and when I try to compile it:

```
$ gcc -ggdb -O0 -fPIC -x c ./pill.c -o pill
```

it gives me the wird error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDhGo05.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `mema' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However the same thing works on an online compiler: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/RYWjy8

... except if I move the variable `mema` to be a local variable in the function `test4` when it complains both places about

```
undefined symbol `mema'
```

And another weirdity: same stuff works when compiled with clang.

Any idea why this happens? (Not considering the required privilege level for `STR`, and other thingies, I am just interested in the linking error and why does it work on one system / compiler and not on another.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `asm("str mema\n");` the compiler literally writes `str mema` into the assembly file.

In a program compiled with `-fPIC` the assembly code is not allowed to contain any addresses of anything in the program (that's what position-independent *means*). So you aren't allowed to have an instruction that contains the address of a global variable `mema`.

Local variables aren't things that the assembler knows about to begin with.

If you want an assembly instruction to read or write a variable, you need to tell the compiler what you want to read or write, and let the compiler figure out what exact code to write:

```
asm("str %0" : "=m" (mema));
```

`"=m"` says that the value is an output (`=`) and it has to be a memory location (`m`) but the compiler gets to figure out what the actual location should be.

[The GCC manual has more information](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) (clang works the same way).